# Identityserver3 Authentication Flow

Tags: identityserver3

I'm trying to do a customer based application, where a user can have multiple customers, but he can only authenticate at one at the time. Is possible to change the customer passing the current token, so that the user won't need to send username/password again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I am guessing that you want to have a user who has been authenticated do things on _behalf_ of a customer? Is this correct?

Comment: not really, the customer is actually a setting from the user. Each user have access to a set of customers, on where it will have different roles.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you are trying to do. Please update your question with more information. If you are creating a customer application, what has it to do with the user? If the user is logged in and has the right roles, everything should work fine... The customer CRUD part is of your application.

Comment: It might be that we are having an issue with jargon here. @Felipeloest, are you saying a _user_ can take on the _identity_ of a customer and that each of these identities can have a different set of roles? Perhaps if you could give us an example usage scenario things would be clearer.

Comment: Well yeah i think i need to change a bit the words in here. So the customer isn't a person, its more like establishment.